Face Selection Issue in Geometry Nodes for odd Grid X & Y inputs
I created a basic Checkerboard extrusion grid pattern using Geo nodes :-

It works fine when grid node, vertices X and Vertices Y are both even or when either one of it is even, but it gives strange result when both are odd :-

Is this a bug, or there is a proper way to do it?

This is a simple math fact. Indices of a grid increase in columns going up (2D up, i.e. $+y$), then right ($+x$):
 Imgur mirror (SE hosting has problems)
BTW, those indices are stable and not subject to change in future versions of Blender, just tested with "Set Geometry Randomization" operator.
Blender 4.0 Manual: Geometry Nodes: Inspection: Geometry Randomization
Now if there's an odd number of faces in the column, then one of the indices doesn't have a pair and so the first indices of columns alternate between being odd and even. Look below, the arrow goes from first element of the pair (even index in 0-based indexing) to 2nd element of the pair (odd index):
 Imgur mirror
This doesn't happen for an even number of elements in a column.
You may want an algorithm like this:

Imgur mirror
For any number of dimensions, you can just add indices of all dimensions and do the mod 2 once:

Imgur mirror

For this, you will have to alternate rows.
I created an "index" solution and a "position" solution. The index one is easier, but I thought of it only after I finished the hard one (lol)

Solution 1

Solution 2

File:

